# how to change color of buttons + change output status when input status changes

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

For school im making a GUI with Tkinter. Now i have a problem where i have to read the input from a GPIO port expander (mcp23008) and use that input too:

1. change color of a button
2. change the status of outputs

This might sound fairly simple (it did too me at first) but it gets too difficult for me when certain things are in different 'def' functions.

This is the setup of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL as p
import PIL.ImageTk as ptk
import smbus
import time

#adafruit
import board
import busio
from digitalio import Direction
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23008 import MCP23008
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp = MCP23008(i2c,address=0x21)
import digitalio

#setup i²c chips
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
#MCP23017
DEVICE = 0x20 #Device address (A0-A2)
IODIRA = 0x00 #pin direction register
IODIRB = 0x00
OLATA  = 0x14 #register for outputs.
OLATB  = 0x15
GPIOA  = 0x12 #register for inputs
GPIOB  = 0x13

#set all GPA pins as outputs by setting
#all bits of IODIRA register to 0
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,IODIRA,0x00)

#set output all 7 output bits to 0
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,0)

#set all GPA pins as outputs by setting
#all bits of IODIRB register to 0
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,IODIRB,0x00)

#set output all 7 output bits to 0
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATB,0)

#MCP23008
DEVICE2 = 0x21
IODIR   = 0x00
GPIO    = 0x09

#set all GPA pins as inputs by setting
#all bits of IODIRA register to 1
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE2,IODIR,0xFF)

#all pins on mcp23008 are inputs
pin0 = mcp.get_pin(0)
pin0.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT



global alpha
alpha = 0

#variables for 'relais' windwow
global ledstate1
ledstate1 = 0
global ledstate2
ledstate2 = 0
global ledstate3
ledstate3 = 0
```

Then i make my window and frame

```
#make mainwindow
mainwindow=Tk()
mainframe=Frame(mainwindow,bg='linen')
mainframe.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
mainwindow.geometry('800x480')
mainwindow.resizable(False,False)
mainwindow.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

#make frame
menu=Frame(mainframe,bg='linen',highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
menu.pack(side='top',fill='x')
```

This is the 'big' def function where i open my second window

```
#this is a def function where i open a second window with 9 buttons for my 9 outputs
def open_relais():
    #window aanmaken
    win = Toplevel(bg='linen')          
    win.title('first window')
    win.geometry('800x480')
    win.resizable(False,False)
    win.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
    #frame maken
    relais = Frame(win,bg='linen')
    relais.pack()                       # put the frame at the top of the window
    #labels onderdelen aanmaken
    #welk onderdeel
    Label14=Label(relais, text='3 Fasen',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)
    Label15=Label(relais, text='1 Fase + aarding',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)
    Label16=Label(relais, text='1 Fase geïsoleerd',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)

    Label14.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=20,pady=15,sticky='new')
    Label15.grid(column=1,row=2,padx=20,pady=15,sticky='new')
    Label16.grid(column=1,row=4,padx=20,pady=15,sticky='new')
   
    #button 1 , together with Stop_bus_3F_1(Stop_bus_3F)
    Stop_bus_3F = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact + Bussen',command=lambda: Stop_bus_3F_1(Stop_bus_3F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_bus_3F.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate1 else "red")
    #button 2 , together with Stop_3F_1(Stop_3F)
    Stop_3F = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact',command=lambda: Stop_3F_1(Stop_3F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_3F.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate2 else "red")
    #button 3, together with Bus_3F_1(Bus_3F)
    Bus_3F = Button(relais,text='Bussen',command=lambda: Bus_3F_1(Bus_3F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Bus_3F.grid(column=2,row=1,padx=20,pady=12)
    Bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate3 else "red")

    #close button second window
    close_button = Button(relais, text='close window', command=win.destroy).grid(column=1,row=6,padx=20,pady=15)
```

Then i make def functions to turn on/off my leds

```
# this are the def functions too turn the outputs on/off without changing other outputs
# 3FASE
def Stop_bus_3F_1(Stop_bus_3F):
    if ledstate2 == 0:                  
        if ledstate3 == 0:              
            global ledstate1
            global alpha
            ledstate1 = 1 - ledstate1
            if ledstate1 == 1:          
                alpha = alpha | 1            
            else:
                alpha = alpha & 254            
            print(alpha)
            Stop_bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate1 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,alpha)
def Stop_3F_1(Stop_3F):
    if ledstate1 == 0:
        if ledstate3 == 0:
            global ledstate2
            global alpha
            ledstate2 = 1 - ledstate2
            if ledstate2 == 1:          
                alpha = alpha | 2                
            else:
                alpha = alpha & 253
            print(alpha)
            Stop_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate2 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,alpha)
def Bus_3F_1(Bus_3F):
    if ledstate1 == 0:
        if ledstate2 == 0:
            global ledstate3
            global alpha
            ledstate3 = 1 - ledstate3
            if ledstate3 == 1:          
                alpha = alpha | 4      
            else:
                alpha = alpha & 251
            print(alpha)
            Bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate3 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,alpha)
```

And then here i poll for my one input, one for now.
here should happen something when the value of pin 0 is false (= real life button is pushed).
What should happen is that the color of the 'Stop_bus_3F' button should change and the other buttons should be turned off. Further should it turn on/off the led that the 'Stop_bus_3F' button controls.

```
#pollen for inputs
def poll_for_data():
    if pin0.value == False:         # 3Fasen knop
        #something has to happen here probably
        print('button pressed')
    mainwindow.after(10, poll_for_data)
```

and last some left over code with buttons

```
#button for second window
button1=Button(menu,text='Bedieningspaneel',command=open_relais,bg='grey89',fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
button1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=36,pady=15,sticky='nsew')

#button too close mainwindow
button4=Button(menu,text='     close     ',command=mainwindow.destroy,bg='grey89',fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
button4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=36,pady=15,sticky='e')

#start the poll for the input
mainwindow.after(300, poll_for_data)
mainwindow.mainloop()
```

i know im asking a lot but i've been trying stuff for hours but cant make it work

Comment: Could You reduce Your code to a [mre]? That would help a lot too. If You could just narrow Your issue a bit more. As far as I understand Your issue is changing the color of a button and simulate it getting pressed at the same time, correct?

Comment: You can use `<widget>.config(bg='color')` to reconfigure the background color of a certain widget, in this case a button. For pressing a button You could use `<Button>.invoke()` which will also trigger the callback